# What does Win32 API call SslEncryptPacket() do exactly?

Tags: ssl

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468663(v=vs.85).aspx.
Why do we need to encrypt the entire packet instead of just encrypting the TCP payload? Also I get an error that sslprovider.h does not exist when I try and include it. I am using nmake and I can't find it anywhere on my computer.

Comment: I am working on windows 7. I have ncrypt.dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it *is* encryption of the payload.

As for sslprovider.h - check that you have recent version of platform SDK. The function, as MSDN says, appeared only in Vista and 2008 Server cause you are looking at CNG (new cryptography API introduced in Vista). SChannel also has another API, which has been offered since 2000 or XP. You might need to look at it if you plan to support WinXP.

Comment: How is it different then from other functions like EncryptMessage? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375378(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @Bruce different APIs. EncryptMessage is part of SSPI API, previously you looked at CNG, and as I mentioned there's also SChannel there, and for SChannel EncryptMessage function is also defined: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375390%28v=VS.85%29.aspx .